# S3 static website redirect using htaccess

Tags: amazon-web-services, .htaccess, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am working on migrating a static website to Amazon S3 + Cloudfront. I also have to migrate a htaccess file with over 100 entries. I thought about using AWS Cloud Front function. But I am stuck to how that might work.

If this isnt possible the next option is rewriting the htaccess rules to the JSON format for object redirect in S3.

Or is there a better way that I am not considering?
Thanks

Comment: S3 doesn't support .htaccess.   .htaccess in an Apache directory level configuration file.  S3 isn't running Apache.  If need functionality provided in .htaccess, you shouldn't be using s3.  It sounds like you want to run Apache to host your site, maybe on an ec2 instance.

Comment: In this situation i am kinda restricted by the client

Comment: It sounds to me like the client doesn't know what they want and you need to guide them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 is a *storage solution* not a full-fledged server and it doesn't have redirect rules.

`.htaccess` use case, such as

- Adding redirections for certain URLs
- Loading custom error pages, like 404 pages
- Forcing your site to use HTTPS instead of HTTP

can be handled at the CloudFront distribution settings level with custom error responses, origins, behaviors, and Lambda@edge, so you don't have to be tied up with software-specific configuration files like `.htaccess` and `httpd.conf`.

Familiarize yourself with [Lambda@Egde Use Cases](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/edge/) and [here's a handful of Getting Started resources](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/getting-started/).